# More simple way to login into multiple site/pages

Tags: python

I am not quite happy the way i coded this. Is there a more simple and convenient way to code this in one function and return the output of multiple pages.

```
def login():
        url = "http://192.168.2.45/pricelogin.php"
        r = requests.get(url, auth=('pstats', 'pStats'))
        page = r.text
        return page

def loginhighpricingerror():
        pricingerrorurl = "http://192.168.2.45/airline_error.pl"
        peu = requests.get(pricingerrorurl, auth=('pstats', 'pstats'))
        peupage = peu.text
        return peupage

def loginsuccessfullbookings():
        sucurl = "http://192.168.2.45/airlinessucbookings.php"
        suc = requests.get(sucbookingurl, auth=('pstats', 'pstats'))
        sucpage = suc.text
        return sucpage
```

Answer (score 1):

Use session instead of sessionless module functions:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth=('pstats', 'pStats')

def login():
        url = "http://192.168.2.45/pricelogin.php"
        r = s.get(url)
        page = r.text
        return page

def loginhighpricingerror():
        pricingerrorurl = "http://192.168.2.45/airline_error.pl"
        peu = s.get(pricingerrorurl)
        peupage = peu.text
        return peupage

def loginsuccessfullbookings():
        sucurl = "http://192.168.2.45/airlinessucbookings.php"
        suc = s.get(sucbookingurl)
        sucpage = suc.text
        return sucpage
```

Of course this should be refactored, but hopefully you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would generalize the login function, passing the url as parameter:

```
def login(url):
   try:
      r = requests.get(url, auth=('pstats', 'pStats'))
   except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
      print e
      return '' # but maybe you want to do something else

   page = r.text
   return page
```

And then you can run it for each url accumulating the pages in an array for example:

```
urls = ["http://192.168.2.45/pricelogin.php", "http://192.168.2.45/airline_error.pl", "http://192.168.2.45/airlinessucbookings.php"]

pages = [] # resulting array
for url in urls:
   pages.append(login(url))
```

**Note**: I added a check on an exception for `requests.get` since this might fail when there is a connection problem.

Comment: Don't you think this way will take time since the for loop will go to every webpage and return the output...

Comment: Yes, but you want to have the text of all pages, don't you?

Comment: Yes but in my earlier code, different function have different purpose. In your case the output which is return (page) contains all the pages which i may or may not use based on the business logic.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question, in your example the only difference between the functions is the url.